# Groovy Global Closure not working in nested method call

Tags: groovy, scope, closures

I have a simple closure that i want to be able to use across my code to measure the time it takes for any other closure. It looks like this:

```
def benchmark = {name,closure ->
    start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    ret =  closure.call()
    now = System.currentTimeMillis()   println(name + " took: " +  (now - start))
    ret
}
```

It works when its invoked from the same scope, like this:

```
benchmark('works') { println("Hello, World\n")}
```

But it doesn't seem to work when its invoked a nested scope

```
def nested()
{
   benchmark('doesnt_work'){print("hello")}
}

nested()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you're running it in a script.

Groovy converts the above into:

```
class Script {
    def run() {
        def benchmark = {name,closure -> ...
        nested()
    }

    def nested() {
        benchmark('doesnt_work'){print("hello")}
    }
}
```

So as you can see, the Closure is local to the implicit `run` method, but the `nested` method belongs to the class...

I believe you have 3 options:

1. Make `nested` a Closure, and they will both exist in the same scope

   ```
   def benchmark = {name,closure ->
       start = System.currentTimeMillis()
       ret =  closure.call()
       now = System.currentTimeMillis()
       println(name + " took: " +  (now - start))
       ret
   }

   def nested = {
      benchmark('doesnt_work'){print("hello")}
   }

   nested()
   ```
2. Write a proper class and control the scoping yourself

   ```
   class Test {
       def benchmark = {name,closure ->
           long start = System.currentTimeMillis()
           def ret =  closure.call()
           long now = System.currentTimeMillis()
           println(name + " took: " +  (now - start))
           ret
       }

       def nested() {
           benchmark('doesnt_work'){print("hello")}
       }

       static main( args ) {
           new Test().nested()
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add `@groovy.transform.Field` before `def benchmark = {name,closure -> ...` this will move the closure definition up to being a [property of this Script class](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/Field.html)

   ```
   @groovy.transform.Field def benchmark = { name, closure ->
       start = System.currentTimeMillis()
       ret =  closure.call()
       now = System.currentTimeMillis()
       println(name + " took: " +  (now - start))
       ret
   }

   def nested() {
      benchmark('doesnt_work'){print("hello")}
   }

   nested()
   ```

Comment: used the Field option, as its doesn't disturb the script flow in other ways